# TunkRank in Mathematica

Tags: function, math, recursion, wolfram-mathematica, ranking

I'm trying out Mathematica for the first time and using [TunkRank](http://thenoisychannel.com/2009/01/13/a-twitter-analog-to-pagerank/) as my algorithm of choice. Here is what I came up with:

```
Following = {{2, 3, 4}, {0, 4}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {0, 2}}
Followers = {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {0, 4}, {0, 2}, {0, 1, 3}}
p = 0.05
Influence[x_] := Influence[x] =
    Sum[1 + (p * Influence[Followers[[x, i]]])/(1 + 
        Length[Following[[x]]]), {i, 0, Length[Followers[[x]]]}]
```

If you run this in Mathematica you will see that it doesn't operate on just the follower nodes . Instead, the recursion is infinite. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And how are you calling your function?

Comment: And by the way, Welcome to StackOverflow! Please vote-up answers you like using the vote buttons, and don't forget to accept the answer you like as the final answer using the checkmark button. You may want to wait a little for more answers to come in before doing that.

Comment: Here is the working algorithm for the first iteration:

    Following = {{3, 4, 5}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {1, 3}};
    Followers = {{2, 5}, {3, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 4}};
    Influence1[x_ , P_: 0.01] := 
        Influence1[x] = 
            Sum[1 + (P*1)/(1 + Length[Following[[x]]]), {i, 
                Length[Followers[[x]]]}];

    Do[t = Influence1[i]; Print[t], {i, 5}];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a start, you might want to consider making `p` a parameter with a default value (see [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html)). Something like `Influence[x_,p_?Positive:0.05]:= (* definition *)`.

Second, you are setting the part specification `i` to start at 0. In Mathematica, indices start at 1, not 0. You will end up getting the `Head` of the object. In this case, `Followers[[x,0]]` will return `List`. You need to change this and increment your data by 1.

```
Following = {{3, 4, 5}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {1, 3}};
Followers = {{2, 5}, {3, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 4}};
Influence[x_, P_: 0.05] := 
 Influence[x] = 
  Sum[1 + (P*Influence[Followers[[x, i]]])/(1 + 
      Length[Following[[x]]]), {i, Length[Followers[[x]]]}]
```

Third, you have some recursiveness in your data. Person 1 is followed by person 2, who is followed by 3 and 4, who are both followed by 1. So of course it is recursive.

```
follows = Join @@ Thread /@ Thread[Following -> Range@5]
 {3 -> 1, 4 -> 1, 5 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 5 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 4 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 
 5 -> 4, 1 -> 5, 3 -> 5}

GraphPlot[follows, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

You could consider an explicit `FixedPoint` type of iteration, using `Chop` or the `SameTest` option to prevent recursion for ever with small changes. But I doubt even that will avoid the problem with a test data set as cyclical as yours.

**EDIT**

ok so I worked out the iterative solution. First you need to convert your followers data into an adjacency matrix.

```
(* Following = {{3, 4, 5}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {1, 3}}; *)
Followers = {{2, 5}, {3, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 4}};

adjmatrix = PadRight[SparseArray[List /@ # -> 1] & /@ Followers]
```

```
{{0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
 {0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
 {1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
 {1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
 {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}}
```

This gives the bit equivalent to the `Length` statements in your version.

```
vec1 = Table[1, {5}]  (* {1, 1, 1, 1, 1} *)

adjmatrix.vec1

vec1.adjmatrix
```

```
{2, 2, 2, 2, 3}
```

```
{3, 2, 2, 2, 2}
```

Convergence is fast.

```
 NestList[1 + 0.02 * adjmatrix.#1/(1 + vec1.adjmatrix) &, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 5]
{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1.01, 1.01333, 1.01333, 1.01333, 1.02}, {1.01017, 
 1.01351, 1.01353, 1.01349, 1.02024}, {1.01017, 1.01351, 1.01354, 
 1.01349, 1.02025}, {1.01017, 1.01351, 1.01354, 1.01349, 
 1.02025}, {1.01017, 1.01351, 1.01354, 1.01349, 1.02025}}
```

Given the adjacency matrix, you can have a function:

```
TunkRank[mat_?MatrixQ, p_?Positive] :=
 With[{vec = Table[1, {Length[mat]}]},
 FixedPoint[1 + p * mat.#1/(1 + vec.mat) &, vec]]
```

Hope that helps. I assume this is giving the right answers.

Comment: FYI - All nodes start with an influence value of 1.

Comment: @AnonConfused That's fine. The algorithm will still cycle and thus get into a recursion loop, because Influence[1] depends on Influence[3] which depends on Influence[1]. I don't think there is a way around that with your data set.

Comment: Way around -> Iterations:

Following = {{3, 4, 5}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {1, 
   3}}; Followers = {{2, 5}, {3, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 3}, {1, 2, 4}};
TunkRank = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
Influence4[x_, P_: 0.5] := 
 Influence4[x] = 
  Sum[(1 + P*TunkRank[[Followers[[x, i]]]])/(1 + 
      Length[Following[[Followers[[x, i]]]]]), {i, 
    Length[Followers[[x]]]}]; Do[
 TunkRank = Influence4 /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; Print[TunkRank], {i, 5}];

Comment: @Verbeia I might have beaten you by a couple of minutes to the problem with the code, but you deserve a lot more upvotes than I can give for persevering and following through with the TunkRank algorithm :)

Comment: @yoda you're very kind. I needed a break from the problem I was having with bar charts (see my recent question).

Comment: For a complete implementation, one would need to (a) make sure it works with explicit `SparseMatrix` objects, (b) check the matrix is square and (c) check it only has 1s and 0s in it. I didn't bother doing this.

Comment: As with PageRank, you can compute the rank iteratively or algebraically.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a variant for the iterations shown in a comment. It uses generation indexing so as to allow memoization.

```
In[104]:= Do[influence[0][j] = 1, {j, 5}];

influence[j_][x_] := 
 influence[j][x] = 
  Sum[(1 + p*influence[j - 1][followers[[x, i]]])/(1 + 
      Length[following[[followers[[x, i]]]]]), {i, 
    Length[followers[[x]]]}];

In[105]:= Do[Print[influence[j] /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}];, {j, 10}];

During evaluation of In[105]:= {1.,1.,0.875,0.875,1.375}

During evaluation of In[105]:= {1.0625,0.9583333333333333,0.9375,0.8541666666666666,1.354166666666667}

During evaluation of In[105]:= {1.052083333333333,0.9652777777777777,0.9418402777777777,0.8723958333333333,1.3515625}

During evaluation of In[105]:= {1.052806712962963,0.9690393518518517,0.9401041666666666,0.8718171296296295,1.354456018518518}

During evaluation of In[105]:= {1.053915895061728,0.968653549382716,0.94067684220679,0.8716182002314814,1.355076919367284}

During evaluation of In[105]:= {1.053955078125,0.9687158404063785,0.94091897344393,0.871852293917181,1.355118111818416}

During evaluation of In[105]:= {1.053972325370799,0.9687952112268517,0.9409307367353609,0.87189754700628,1.355172407152885}

During evaluation of In[105]:= {1.053994603063289,0.9688047139569401,0.9409419418634972,0.8719016634605767,1.355195333710205}

During evaluation of In[105]:= {1.054000007944524,0.9688072675540123,0.9409485476679453,0.871906315693494,1.355200388285831}

During evaluation of In[105]:= {1.054001275973307,0.9688091438935732,0.9409500657073706,0.8719080922710565,1.35520226486765}
```

I think it is better to just set up and solve a linear system. Can be done as below.

```
In[107]:= NSolve[
 Table[inf[x] == 
   Sum[(1 + p*inf[followers[[x, i]]])/(1 + 
       Length[following[[followers[[x, i]]]]]), {i, 
     Length[followers[[x]]]}], {x, 5}], inf /@ Range[5]]

Out[107]= {{inf[1] -> 1.054002220652064, inf[2] -> 0.9688099323710506,
   inf[3] -> 0.940950842838397, inf[4] -> 0.8719087513879075, 
  inf[5] -> 1.355203391541334}}
```

This is related to the iterative approach above insofar as that isone method of solving such a linear system (it is the Jacobi method).

Answer (score 2):

The first problem I see is that the input to your function is 0. Consider the term `Followers[[x, i]]` in your definition of `Influence`. [Recall that](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html?q=Part&lang=en) `Part` 0 of an expression gives you its `Head`.

So `Following[[0]]` (when `x=0`) will give you `List` and `Followers[[0,0]]` (which is the case when `x=0` and `i=0`) will give you `Symbol`, which is the `Head` of `List`. I don't think that is what you want.

Secondly, in such recursive definitions, usually there are one or two seed values/starter values/initial values whatever you call them. For example, the Fibonacci equation in recursive form is

```
f[0]=1;
f[1]=1;
f[n_]:=f[n]=f[n-1]+f[n-2]
```

where you've defined `f` for the first two cases `0` and `1`. However, in your function, there is no such initialization and there is the likelihood that it just runs in circles.

There's not much more I can say without knowing what the TunkRank algorithm is.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the [TunkRank post](http://thenoisychannel.com/2009/01/13/a-twitter-analog-to-pagerank/) that I wrote and someone else cited:

> The recursion is infinite over a graph with directed cycles, but
>   rapidly converges as high powers of p approach zero. I would think
>   this measure wouldn’t be hard to compute to a reasonable accuracy.

Even if there are no directed cycles, you might as well stop the computation when the numbers get small enough.

Good luck with TunkRank, and feel free to reach out to me at dtunkelang@gmail.com if you have any questions about it!

Comment: Thanks, it's why I suggested the `FixedPoint` approach. But his test data set is so small and cyclic that it never gets there.

Comment: Correction - it does converge if put together properly. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @Daniel It can be recast and solved as a linear system. The iterations are one way of solving the system, but by no means the only way.

Comment: @Licktblau Can you expand on that?

Comment: @Verbeia The platform I'm using has an FPU, so there should be no advantage to using FixedPoint.

Comment: @AnonCosfused I think you may have meant to add this to my answer. Anyway, I am not suggesting that my approach was the best to help you see your way to a better solution.

Comment: @AnonConfused My response shows how to cast it directly as a linear system. Also mentions the iterative solving method that has appeared in some responses and/or comments.